# Ratio between two sets of numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have two sets of numbers. The first set is 1 to 4. The second set is 0 to 190. What is the calculation to get the proportionate number in the second set if a number in the first set is, for example, 1.2? Math is not my forte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\displaystyle\frac{1.2-1}{4-1}\cdot (190-0) +0$.

Comment: Can you express that equation without the fraction? For a programming equation?

Comment: If your input is $x$, then to go from $[1,4]$ to $[0,190]$, compute $(x-1)*190/3$.

Comment: That's it, thanks!